# WP7 Streaming HTTP audio

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio-streaming, background-agents

Trying to use the BackgroundAudioAgent just like a previous post:
[How do I stream an MP3 over HTTP in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490356/how-do-i-stream-an-mp3-over-http-in-the-background/9493506#9493506)

The answer says to just put the radioreference.relay.com URL in an AudioTrack object.

Here's my code:

```
        // A playlist made up of AudioTrack items.
    private static List<AudioTrack> _playList = new List<AudioTrack>
    {
        new AudioTrack(new Uri("Ring01.wma", UriKind.Relative), 
                        "Ringtone 1", 
                        "Windows Phone", 
                        "Windows Phone Ringtones", 
                        //new Uri("shared/media/Ring01.jpg", UriKind.Relative)),
                        null),

        // A remote URI
        new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://relay.radioreference.com:80/346246215", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                            "Title",
                            "Artist",
                            "Album",
                            null),


        // A remote URI
        new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://traffic.libsyn.com/wpradio/WPRadio_29.mp3", UriKind.Absolute), 
                        "Episode 29", 
                        "Windows Phone Radio", 
                        "Windows Phone Radio Podcast",
                        //new Uri("shared/media/Episode29.jpg", UriKind.Relative))
                        null)
    };
```

From there it's just the sample code from Microsoft (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=226292).

The first and third track from the sample play, but the radioreference.com track doesn't work.  I've tried removing the :80, changing the UriKind to Absolute, removing the http, etc.  It winds up calling the OnError handler in the sample code and just bails out.

Any other ideas on this?

Comment: [Please check this Question and my answer, it may help you.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490356/how-do-i-stream-an-mp3-over-http-in-the-background/9493506#9493506

Comment: That's what I was refering to, but it doesn't work for me.  Do you have code that actually works with the URL listed in my code?  I know it's valid because I can play it with a MediaElement no problem.

Comment: Are you able play same url file with any other streaming player like , WMP or media element ??

Comment: Yes.  I was able to play directly with MediaElement.  See my answer below.  I just had to add .mp3 to the end.  *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently for relay.radioreference.com I actually just had to add the .mp3 extension, even though it's not required by MediaElement.

```
            new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://relay.radioreference.com/346246215.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                            "Title 3",
                            "Artist",
                            "Album",
                            null),
```

Duh.  Hopefully this helps someone else who's using relay.radioreference.com.